# About inserting image in "CREO" Drawing file

Tags: vb.net, api, automation

Respected all,

For automation purpose, I want to insert an image(png/jpg) in drawing file (.drw) using VB API.
if possible kindly request you to provide any suggestion regarding this.
In case if there is any other way then please let me know.

Regards,
Dharmendra Patel

Comment: Dim asyncConnection As IpfcAsyncConnection = Nothing
        Dim model As IpfcModel
        Dim session As IpfcBaseSession
        'ver for past
        Dim activeServer As IpfcServer
        Dim workspaceName As String
        Dim workspacePath As String
        'end
        asyncConnection = (New CCpfcAsyncConnection).Start(PATHOF_SOFTWARE_EXE, ".")
        session = asyncConnection.Session
        session.ChangeDirectory("DIRECTORY")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to insert an image in a drw file using vb api. But you can try this record a mapkey of inserting the image. Get the mapkey string and send it to CREO (probably after editing the filename of the image in vb.net) using the RunMacro() command.

Refer: Macros topic in creo vb user guide

Comment: Hello Pratheesh,

I've checked with your given way.
Complete map-key is not being recorded.

Can you please suggest further way on this?

Or you can provide your Map-key string for importing image using paint tool.